# Ninject in ASP.NET MVC with two repositories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository, ninject.web.mvc

I am working with ninject and I have problem with multiple repositories and interfaces. I managed to make ninject for one repo and one interface but problem appears when I am trying to ninject another repo with another interface with same database context.
What is solution for multiple repositories and interfaces which are using same database context?

NinjectWebCommon.cs

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        //First one is working 
        kernel.Bind<IBookingRepo>().To<BookingsRepo>();
        //I suppose it can not be here
        kernel.Bind<IRestaurantRepo>().To<RestaurantRepo>();
    }
```

second repository

```
    public class RestaurantRepo : IRestaurantRepo
        {
            //should i initialize second time db?
            ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        ...
        }
```

Comment: You should inject your ApplicationDbContext instead of create a new instance inside your repository class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your Ninject kernel to inject the same concrete instance of ApplicationDbContext in all your repositories and change your repositories constructors to receive the instance.

NinjectWebCommon.cs:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IBookingRepo>().To<BookingsRepo>();
        kernel.Bind<IRestaurantRepo>().To<RestaurantRepo>();
    }
```

Your Repositories:

```
public class RestaurantRepo : IRestaurantRepo
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public RestaurantRepo(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    //...
}
```